# Redux multilevel nested entities

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, flux

I've got some data that looks like:

```
videoGameCharacter:
----data
----actionSequence:
--------data
--------actionsArray:
------------data
```

and so on.. So my corresponding characterReducer holds an array of videoGameCharacter objects.

**The question :**

a) would you recommend i broke this up into a less nested format making it more flat and referencing everything with keys? I dont know if it should make a difference at all. Its the first time im dealing with data that belongs together so strictly having this many nested entitities with nested entities.

b) if not, should the one api call retrieve data in this format or should i keep the data in the corresponding seperate api calls? currently iv e structured my api call to return data as displayed above and even though this saves me some extra calls to the server it makes things a bit more complex.

Comment: what's the purpose of actionSequence, actionArray? Do you have sample of the state?

Comment: a character has action sqeuence objects which have action objects. When they perform an actionsqeuence i loop through it and actions then perform operations relevant to those. Actions might have subactions. The important thing to note is that only a character object has actionsequence objects and only an actionsequence object has action objects so these things are conceptually tied together.

Comment: you retrieve from somewhere the actionSequence and actionsArray?

Comment: yeah through the api call. this relates to question b). Currently its all in one api call but can be ofc broken in many.

Comment: I think it's preferable to have directly actionSequence in the character object and access to it. For me it's not the purpose of the Redux store to  have a specific state entry for this kind of data.

Comment: i see. so essentiall you re saying, keep it as is correct?

Comment: have you read [this](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html)?